# What determines the default FLS settings when creating a new field

Tags: profile, fields, field-level-security, fls

In step 3 of the create new field wizard, you are presented with a page like this:

[image: Default settings for step 3 of field creation wizard]

Why do some of the profiles get default visibility and some don't?

There is probably an extremely simple profile based explanation out there, but I've never seen it.

If anyone knows why this occurs, it'd be great to have an explanation of this.

Comment: Does no-one know why this is? Or is it so obvious that it's not worth answering?

Comment: wondering if this is based on the type of license associated with the profile? is there a different license associated with the profiles for which it gets defaulted vs the ones for which it is not defaulted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to Rajiv's comment, This is due to the type of User Licenses for each of these profiles. 
Profiles with Salesforce User License have visible selected and the ones with community or portal licenses etc do not have default visible field selected for them.

This is based on my observation/experience and I do not find it written anywhere in documentation.

Comment: Doggone me, I think you are right!