# Field Level Security for new fields

Tags: field-level-security

When creating new fields, some profiles are checked by default on page load.
How are these profiles determined ?

Comment: Interesting question, I always wondered same

Comment: Which profiles are unticked for you?

Comment: Which profiles means ..?

Comment: Same question: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/76105/what-determines-the-default-fls-settings-when-creating-a-new-field?rq=1

Comment: @javanoob True enough, but it doesn't include a link to the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=adding_fields.htm&type=5):

> When you create a custom field, by default the field isn’t visible or editable for portal profiles, unless the field is universally required.

So, the answer is, if you don't check the Required checkbox, portal users don't get field access by default.

At a more technical level, I believe this means that only profiles with the Salesforce license type will get checked by default.

Comment: The last paragraph is correct. Other users who don't get access by default: Guest (Site & Community users)